# Динамическое создание статичных объектов

Tags: массивы, typedef, указатели, c++

Пытаюсь получить функцию, которая, приняв на вход указатель на матрицу 4*4, делает её единичной. Матрица определяется как синоним float[16]. Как мне теперь в коде динамически создать эту матрицу?

```
typedef float M[16];

void M_M_SetIdentity(M * src)
{
    *src[0] = 1;
    *src[1] = 0;
    *src[2] = 0;
    *src[3] = 0;
    *src[4] = 0;
    *src[5] = 1;
    *src[6] = 0;
    *src[7] = 0;
    *src[8] = 0;
    *src[9] = 0;
    *src[10] = 1;
    *src[11] = 0;
    *src[12] = 0;
    *src[13] = 0;
    *src[14] = 0;
    *src[15] = 1;

}

void main()
{
    M *mat = new M[sizeof(M)]; // Эта строка создаст 16 матриц или одну матрицу из 16        элементов или вообще 64 матрицы?
    M_M_SetIdentity(mat);
    std::ofstream outfile("outthis.txt");
    outfile.open("outthis.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        outfile << *mat[i];
    }
    delete[]mat;
}
```

Comment: Один массив на 16 элементов float. Матрицы двумерны.

Comment: Да, похоже и правда создает одну матрицу, как и нужно. Такой строкой проверил `outfile <<sizeof(*mat)/sizeof(*mat[0]);`